# Style Text Android Wear Card Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os

For my Android Wear application I have a few card fragments in a FragmentGridPagerAdapter. However the font size for the title and text in the cards is very small.

Is it possible to style the title and text in a card fragment using different font types and font sizes? If so, how would you go about doing this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the content of your Card Fragment and so change textSize in the layout of your Fragment :

```
<android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/custom_card"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
```

Show [the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/cards.html#card-fragment).

Comment: Okay thanks @lopez.mikhael, but is there a way of doing it through code? See I'm not using a layout to create the card fragments, the text and title values are coming from a mobile and I have to pass these values in when instantiating the cards  (eg, CardFragment fragment=CardFragment.create(title, text);

Comment: If you don't use a layout to create the card fragment you can't change the font size for the title and text.

Comment: Okay, no problem. I will try to use layout to create them. Thanks Lopez